# Handle multiple countdowns in Android

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I have a timer in my application that decreases its value by one each second. I would like to show this value on different activities. This timer also runs on each activity. If I start activity A, the timer starts from 50. After 10 seconds, the user starts activity B and comes back to A after 10 seconds. Activity A must show a timer value of 30.

What would be the best way to do that on each activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should use countdown service and just bind to it when activity starts.